# Track IP Address of Users Clicking on Adsense Ads

Tags: php, javascript, adsense

on my website I have adsense ads. I am getting attacked by click booming. Basically I want to detect when the user is clicking the ads so I can record the IP in my data base then I will be able to ban the user with the most clicks. Now I understand that most adsense ads runs through iframe tab, but can I still do what I want ?
Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tested this, but it should work. It basically checks if the mouse was over the ad before the blur event was fired.

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

  var isOverGoogleAd = false;

  $( "iframe[ id *= google ]" ).mouseover(
      function(){
          isOverGoogleAd = true;
      }
  )
  .mouseout(
      function(){
          isOverGoogleAd = false;
      }
  );

  $( window ).blur(
      function(){

      if (isOverGoogleAd){

          $.ajax({
              type: "post",
              url: "track.php",
              data: {
                  adUrl: window.location.href
              }
          });
      }
  })
  .focus();
});
```

Taken from [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1752-Tracking-Google-AdSense-Clicks-With-jQuery-And-ColdFusion.htm).